# Accessing Objective-C NSError** methods in Swift

Tags: swift, try-catch, throw, nserror

ObjC method: `-(id)objectFromData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error`

Swift translated Method: `func object(from data: Data!) throws -> Any`

I am calling this translated func VIA do try Catch in swift. objC implementation of 'objectFromData' is

```
    -(id)objectFromData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
    {
        *error = [NSError errorWithText:@"Unable to get Data, Please try later"];
        return @"testing";
    }
```

I am accessing like

```
let objCVar : ParserBase = ParserBase()
do {
    try objCVar.object(from: data)
} catch {
    print("Catched ObjC Error")
}
```

Error is not catched this way. Please guide how to get objc NSerror in above case.

Note:  I can't use change objC method to 'Void' method to avoid throws translation because of enterprise scope of application.

Comment: Shouldn't the method return `nil` if there is an error?

Comment: Great, returning nil did the trick.